# In TeXnicCenter I'm trying to produce a PDF but no output is being created

Tags: pdf, compiling, texniccenter

Very simple really.
I installed TeXnicCenter, Adobe Reader X and MiKTeX 2.9.

Tried to build a code in the PDF format. I get 4 new files but no .pdf file.
Yet another option listed as LaTeX => PS => PDF does produce the required result?

What is going on?

Comment: Hard to tell without some more information. If I understood your question correctly, the profile LaTeX=>PS=>PDF gives you a final PDF document, while the compilation through LaTeX=>PDF fails? If that is so, then perhaps your document contains Postscript material (for example, code from PS-Tricks or images in EPS format) which requires the first compilation profile.

Comment: That is correct but it doesn't appear to be a problem with the latex code as it is very simple. The error message Texniccenter produces is: [DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")] Cannot execute the command.

Comment: I've just attempted to build another code and now only .log file is being produced and no build profile is working...

Comment: It seems that the PDF file is in fact produced but TeXnicCenter cannot open it with your viewer. Compile with the problematic profile and then go to the folder containing the .tex file and see if the PDF file was produced (you can open it manually); that would mean that the problem comes from the TeXnicCenter settings for the PDF viewer.

Comment: When I said the files were not being produced, I am checking this folder.

Comment: Yes; sorry. I was writing my comment and didn't see your new answer. Have you tried compiling from the command line to rule out a problem with your LaTeX installation?

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Open a terminal (System symbol, I think it's the name in Windows), change the directory to the one containing the .tex file and then run `pdflatex test.tex` (assuming that the name of your file is `test.tex`).

Comment: >Tried to build a code in the PDF format. I get 4 new files but no .pdf file. Yet >another option listed as LaTex => PS => PDF does produce the required result? >What is going on? Could be you simply forgot `\end{document}` at the end.

Comment: On my older computer I had the issue of it producing the PDF but giving the [DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")] error and not opening the file. I've just got a new machine and installed MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter and now I get the same error but no PDF produced at all. I can make it produce PS files instead. I don't have a LaTeX=>PS=>PDF option. Trying to find a solution to the same problem as posted on this thread but I've also had no luck.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/canonical-texniccenter-question

Answer (score 1):

If a pdf is produced (apart from looking in the output folder, TexnicCenter will tell you the number of pages in the pdf file: if that's greater than 0 then the pdf file has been produced) then you may need to adjust the TexnicCenter settings to cope with Adobe Reader X. Full details of how to do this are at [TexnicCenter and Adobe Reader 10 / X](http://www.agmonim.com/2010/12/texniccenter-and-adobe-reader-10-x/). Please also read the comments for extra information.